# Android resource IDs suddenly not final, fields cannot be resolved

Tags: android, string, variables, resources

I'm working on a new-old project... I'm making it for a different country market, and when i copyed my code from an old project it shows some mistake like MIGRATE ANDROID CODE (As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch cases.) This happens for a resourses that are in strings.xml file and for layout.
But it doesn't give me some posible fix... how can i fix it???? Here is code:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Here is mistake
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

          //Kreira AlertDialog sa dva dugmeta koji ce se pojaviti pri aktiviranju aplikacije
            ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
//And HERE
            ad.setTitle(getString(R.string.vasa_trenutna_lokacija));
            //And HERE
ad.setMessage(getString(R.string.da_bi_ste_koristili_aplikaciju));
            //And HERE
            ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getString(R.string.dozvoli), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            //Klikom na dugme Dozvoli otvara se novi prozor
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface ad, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(NiskiMerakActivity.this, TrenutnaLokacija.class);             
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                }
            });

            ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.ne_dozvoli),new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            //Klikom na dugme Ne dozvoli aplikacija se zatvara
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Please post your logcat. I hope,you are not getting error caused by import of R file in your class.

Comment: what error or exception u r getting by the way??????

Comment: Stupid of me!!!! I imported android.R, but for some reson it didn't imported all from R. I add .* at the and and it now seems it's okey!!! Thanks.... Put it like a answer and i will check it true...

Comment: @jovan you should not import android.R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch cases.

This happened to me too, I got this error even though I wasn't using the R variable in a switch statement. Don't be mislead by the error message. You basically have some error that relates to the R.java file. Make sure you don't import R.java since you should have your own. Delete your R.java file, build project, and see if your R.java file gets generated. If not, you could have an error that is preventing your R.java file from being updated. Try Project > Clean to find any errors. Get rid of the errors and rebuild your project so that your R.java file gets generated and is up-to-date.

Comment: This is completely untrue. I'm using ADT 16 and am using resource fields as case variables, and my R file constants are all final.

Comment: @JasonRobinson as of ADT 14 the R constants are not final in library projects. See http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Comment: @johlo Maybe they reverted that change in a later version then, because my IDs are definitely `final` and I'm now using ADT 20.

Comment: See @47lucanae answer below. Toggling the Is Library property definitely switches between these two behaviours in SDK Tools 22.6 / SDK Platform-tools 19.0.1.

Answer (score 13):

Quoting http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

> The solution for this is simple: Convert the switch statement into an if-else statement.

Since your code snippet above does not appear to have a `switch()` statement, yet your question refers to a `switch()` statement, I assume you have the wrong code.

Comment: See a comment under my question...but it refered to a switch statement...i don't know why... Thanks anyway... :D

Answer (score 9):

if your switch-case of the ids is inside a library, sadly the new ADT versions don't support it.

However, you can convert it easily to if-else , as shown on Google's website:

```
http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably you just need to `Clean` your project, i.e. Project -> Clean from the main menu.
There should not be errors in the code above. The problem is only with `switch` statements.
Please try to clean and comment here what is the result.

Comment: See a comment under my question...but it refered to a switch statement...i don't know why... Thanks anyway... :D

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by changing my import from `android.r;` to `android.R.*;`

It cleared all of my errors and i was able to compile my app again.

Comment: You could also just remove that import line to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Today i was facing the same error, my eclipse project have 1 project library added, and i was about to change all the code to if statements, but i realize my project had the library check on, in project ->properties-> android, so i just turn it down and that was the solution to the problem, it also was a suggestion of eclipse itself, reading carefully android migration code adt 14 constants warning for project libraries.

Comment: +1 If the "Is Library" property is ticked, the R file generated declares identifiers as "public static int" rather than "public static final int" - hence the error message. Presumably this is something to do with making identifiers externally visible rather than allowing them to be optimized away by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just select in eclipse project -> clean, and the problem was solved. I got this error just by creating a new package in my app and removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which helps me to resolve this problem.

1. Delete R.java (Eclipse will recreate it immediately. If not there is a problem with the code or layout)
2. Clean the project (Eclipse menu 'Project' & 'Clean'
3. Recompile the project

These steps resolve the problem with my work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Comment: Thanks Kev for your guidance. I will refer my answer in future.

Answer (score 0):

I found it works after changing the import statement for R to include your package name.

For instance:

import android.R;

is now

import com.name.package.R;

Comment: android.R is completely different to com.name.package.R and can't be replaced by each other

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the approaches mentioned above regarding deleting the generated R.java file, clean, rebuild, etc but that approach did not work for me.

What did work was replacing the case with an else-if chain which was a messy fix in my opinion but I couldn't get it to work any other way.

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 and Android SDK 4.2.2