# changing switches to "if-else" statements

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I've just recently become interested in programming, and I want to create Android apps for phones or tablets.  I've come a long way in a couple weeks from knowing almost nothing about java/xml.  I'm very serious about this.  I'm going to find the answer to this question one way or the other.  In fact, I hope to have it figured out before anyone answers this.  I've fixed many issues without resorting to asking anyone, but I've just been stuck on this issue too long. I figured I'd give this a shot.

I'm using an older tutorial to build a practice twitter app (the tutorials for these seem to be everywhere, which is why I chose it).  I'm using Eclipse for an editor.

The following is an example of code from the tutorial. which relates to my question:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timeline);
```

Apparently since the intro of ADT 14, you can no longer use the (R.layout.timeline) phrase, which the error message refers to as a "switch statement."

Now, in a post I found on another site, someone who had a similar issue shows a screenshot of the "quick fix" in Eclipse using ctrl+1.  in the screenshot, the fix that pops up says "convert switch to 'if-else' statement."  This fix does not pop up in my version of Eclipse.  My quick fix options are "migrate Android code", "create field 'timeline' in type 'layout'", "create constant 'timeline' in type 'layout'" or "rename in file."

If I choose "migrate Android code", a window pops up informing me of the ADT 14 update, and how switch statements are no longer allowed in library projects.  It says to convert the switch statement to an "if-else" statement by pressing ctrl+1 for the quick fix, then choosing "switch to 'if-else' statement" like it does in the screenshot I found.  But again, when I do this, that option does not pop up.

I would much rather know what needs to be changed in the code than know how to make the right quick fix pop up.  If it isn't too much trouble, an explanation of why exactly these changes are affective would be very helpful.  I have many (MANY) errors in my java files right now, but most of them are due to this exact problem in different forms.  If I could see just one before/after example I could probably figure it out from there without an explanation.  But after hours of searching, I cannot find that so far by googling.

Thanks so much in advance....

And for the record, I don't see any switch classes in any of my java files, if that makes a difference for the answer...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with **R.layout.timeline**, what error message are you receiving?

Comment: I don't see a switch statement. Are you sure that's where and/or what the error is? Sounds more like you're trying to use an un-defined, or as-of-yet un-compiled resource.

Comment: when I hover over the error message, this is the exact message that pops up: "As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as 
 switch cases. Invoke this fix to get more information."  if I invoke the fix, which is "migrate android code", it pops up a screen which says to use the quick fix, which brought me there in the first place.  this is a quote from the window which pops up if you choose "migrate android code". "As of ADT 14, the resource fields(such as timeline) are no longer constants when defined in library projects.

Comment: "...This is necessary to make library projects reusable without recompiling them.  One consequence of this is that you can no longer use the fields directly in switch statements.  You must use a 'if-else' chain instead."  this is why I thought that was a switch statement, or referred to one...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8547309/1103813 This is what worked for me

Comment: When posting to StackOverflow, if you're not really sure where the issue lies, you can post more of the code than you think you need to.  Unless you are 100% sure that an issue actually occurs on Line 3 (for instance), include maybe the first 15 lines of code in your post.  This might help someone pinpoint the error (or conclude that Eclipse is crying wolf).

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you click on the `switch` keyword itself then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.
This confused me at first as well...

If it still doesn't show up, what version of Eclipse are you using?

If you are using a Mac select the keyword `switch` and click <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd>  + <kbd>1</kbd>.
That will show a prompt to change `switch` to `if else` conditions.

Comment: in the example I showed, would the switch keyword be the "R." in setContentView(R.layout.timeline)   ??

Comment: @brando_fvkTech Eclipse 4.1?! That aside , the switch keyword is just that--"switch". I don't see how the code you posted could cause an error regarding switch statements, nor does Eclipse believe there is a switch statement there--the quick fix points to an undefined resource.

Comment: and yes, I now understand a switch statement strictly refers to where it says "switch" itself.

Comment: @brando_fvkTech There is no Eclipse 4.1, so more or less insane, yep. Current release is 3.8.

Comment: then why does mine say 4.1?  haha hold on, i'm going to find a link to the d/l...

Comment: @DaveNewton while I agree it's unlikely it is possible he's running pre-release version http://download.eclipse.org/e4/sdk/drops/R-4.1-201106201631/

Comment: @brando_fvkTech Don't use a pre-release version, if that's what you're doing. Use something actually known to work, *particularly* when just starting out.

Comment: here's a link to it.  it's in the developer builds section.  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/node/688  in fact, it says 4.2 now....

Comment: I didn't know it was a pre-release version.  it was recommended that I install this version...

Comment: so before anything I should install the normal version of eclipse?

Comment: @brando_fvkTech as Dave Newton said, DO NOT run a pre-release version of eclipse and expect it to work with Android. Download the proper version [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr1), with the links to your OS on the side

Comment: @brando_fvkTech I'd use the latest version from the normal downloads. (3.7 I think, I typoed before.) May not solve your problem, but it will introduce fewer potential issues.

Comment: right on.  at the very least, the quick fix will probably work, and then I can learn the java code from there...

Comment: @brando_fvkTech Possibly. Without seeing context it's difficult to guess where the issue is. If you put the project on github we can look.

Comment: I'm going to look into doing that as soon as I have a chance.  again, thanks for your help...

Comment: I've gotten the current version of eclipse now, and am getting the same errors, but without the weird thing about ADT 14.  I have a feeling the main .java file is totally screwed... haha

Comment: oh man.  you have to install software for this github thing?  not sure I want to do that...

Comment: `alt-return` did this for me in IntelliJ 14 on a mac, but thanks for pushing in the right direction! :D

Comment: You can also convert it the other way around. Simple press CTRL + 1 at the beginning if and choose `convert 'if-else' to 'switch'`

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issues.  For me, I was switching on view.getId().  Before the switch, declare int id = view.getId();.  Then switch in id.  Then you can ctrl+1 click and the "Convert Switch to If/Else" should pop up.

They made this change to decrease the build speed.  My projects now build in roughly 1/10th of the time.  I'm glad I upgraded the ADT.

Comment: Yes, assigning the `id` to a variable instead of getting it over and over for each case is going to save time.  And this is indeed the way to convert a `switch` to an `if-else`.  However, I don't think that this really responds to the question posed....

Answer (score 2):

The issue happens because since ADT 14 resource identifiers are no longer final.
The quick solution you can change switch statements with if-else statements.

With **Android Studio 4.1.3**

Step:1. Just right click on the **switch** keyword of statement.

Step:2  Click on the first option **Show Context Actions.**

Step:3  Click replace `switch` with `if`.

**Done**

Comment: This answer is especially helpful, as it reminded me to use "ALT-Enter"(Linux) more. "show Context actions" is just that: click on an word -> alt+enter -> select switch to if/else

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you don't have a **timeline** resource.

Breaking down **R.layout.timeline**

**R** refers to ***Resources***

**layout** refers to the collection of layouts in your application

and **timeline** refers the specific resource that you are trying to apply **setContentView()** too.

If my hunch is correct, you don't have the **timeline** resource.
Create a new XML file in your layout folder in eclipse and name it 'timeline'
That should resolve the issue.

Comment: I have both a timeline.xml and a timeline.java file.  In fact, the example I posted is from the timeline.java file.  I know exactly which resource it's referring to, and that file exists.  I have found other people with almost this same problem through google searches, but none of the answers I've found apply to any of my specific errors.  part of the problem is probably just that it's an old tutorial.  the resource definitely exists, but the error message says that a switch statement no longer works in a library project, so I'm guessing I need to completely change the approach...

Comment: Your statement here is not quite correct (though I realize that you're a newbie).  A `switch` statement is still perfectly valid to use in Android files on *constant* numeric whole-number types and [enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  (In Java 7, which is not used by Android, [`switch` also works on Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got things working.

I agree that this sounds like some weird Eclipse error that is not what it seems, and not what Quick Fix says it is.  Eclipse has been known to lie from time to time.  Cleaning your project (as @Stephen Dubya said), cutting out the offending code, saving the file, pasting it back in, and saving again...these are some of the non-obvious tricks that sometimes get Eclipse to behave.

In general, I think it would be good for you to get more familiar with some of the [Java basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) like `switch`; I think it will make your learning of Android a lot easier.  Although the tools and documentation keep improving, Android is still young and not always easy to learn using tutorials, especially when you aren't used to writing code at all or using complicated IDEs like Eclipse.

But I digress.  It is only in Android *[library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)*, not regular projects, that Android doesn't treat [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) as constants (`final` variables), since ADT 14.  That means means that in library projects, you can't use `R.layout.timeline` or similar resource variables in your `switch` statements.  You can only `switch` on whole numbers or enum values.

Using `if-else` all the time may be your best bet, anyway.  `switch` can, especially for beginners, lead to logic errors in your code, and anything you can write using `switch` can be rewritten using `if-else` blocks.  Personally, I've stopped using `switch` in Android and other Java code altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the curse right before the s in the word switch, and the press cmd 1 .  If you switch statements have fall-through clauses, the option to convert won't be available.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow I overworked this error. I have deleted my project from workspace. Reverted it's .project files to old ones commited at SVN. Then at Eclipse uninstalling ADT and install it again. Then import my project. - > Libraries are added the old way and as result all fields at R.java are now final. Hope this helps.